# Javascript table multidimension

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello i'm begignner at javascript, I wrote the code below and get this error in my console "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"

```
var tab1=[{0,2,4,6,8},{1,3,5,7}];



console.log(tab1[0][0]);
```

Comment: Objects should contain `key: value` pairs...

Answer (score 2):

Please change the curly to square brackets:

```
var tab1 = [[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 3, 5, 7]];
```

`[]` are used for arrays, `{}` are used for objects.

Examples:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
object = { property: 'one', key: 'two' };
```

Comment: I want exemple the object with (loop for ) and also array ? please ?

Comment: please read T. J. Crowder's superb answer for looping arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is for creating *objects*; it expects key: value pairs inside, which are called *property initializers*.

`[]` is for creating *arrays*.

So if you want to create an array of arrays (JavaScript doesn't have two-dimensional arrays, but arrays of arrays work just as well), use nested `[]`:

```
var tab1=[[0,2,4,6,8],[1,3,5,7]];
```

Just for completeness, here's an example of an *object* rather than array:

```
var obj = {
    question: "Life, the Universe, and Everything",
    answer: 42
};
```

The reason for the error is that you just had `0,2` and it was expecting a `:` after the `0`. (Literal numbers are valid object keys, which is why the `0` wasn't the problem.)

Comment: I want exemple the object with (loop for ) and also array ? please ?

Comment: @hopo: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you're talking about looping through arrays, I wrote a fairly comprehensive answer on it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/157247). (It's a long answer, but really you only need to look at examples 1 and 2.)